# Remove character from dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am sure this is quite elementary, however I haven't found a similar question.
I have a dictionary:

```
tenants = {'John': ['Address1\r'], 'Claudia': ['Address2\r'], 'Mike': ['Address3\r']}
```

How can I remove the "\r" in the values?

Comment: Look into strip().

Comment: What part do you have problems with? Iterating over dictionary keys? Iterating over their values? Removing a single character from the end of a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's `strip` function. The following code is easy to read and works:

```
tenants = {'John': ['Address2\r'], 'Claudia': ['Address2\r'], 'Mike': ['Address3\r']}

print(tenants)

for tenent, adresslines in tenants.items():
    new_lines = []
    for line in adresslines:
        new_lines.append(line.strip())
    tenants[tenent] = new_lines

print(tenants)
```

Comment: split() also do a white spaces cutoff. see my answer below. and be generous if you can :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That did it. I don't have enough reputation to give you points, but you have my gratefulness FWIW :D

Answer (score 1):

```
tenants = {'John': ['Address1\r'], 'Claudia': ['Address2\r'], 'Mike': ['Address3\r']}
for k,v in tenants.items():
    temp=(''.join(v[0].split()))
    val=[]
    val.append(temp)
    tenants[k]=val
print (tenants)
```